# ReactiveKit: How do you get the values of changed entries for ObservableCollection?

Tags: swift, reactivekit

I'm using ReactiveKit 1.x. It has a very helpful `ObservableCollection<T>`, which allows you to monitor for changes to a collection. In my case, I'm using it with `Dictionary<String,String>`

The ObservableCollection produces an event of type `CollectionEventChange<T>`, and it includes properties for `insert`, `update`, `delete`. For dictionary, these are `DictionaryIndex<String,String>`.

In order to examine the contents of `delete` and `update` entries, it seems like I need to keep a reference to the previous collection.

**Is it possible to use the elements listed in these properties to look up the changed entry in the event's `collection` property?**

Am I missing something? (I guess the solution might not have anything to do with ReactiveKit, just general use of Swift Dictionaries.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should go with `zipPrevious` method to get previous event and from it the previous collection.

```
let collection = ObservableCollection(["key": "value"])

collection.zipPrevious().observe { (old, new) in
  guard let old = old else { return } // `old == nil` on first event

  for index in new.deletes {
    let value = old.collection[index]
    print("Deleted \(value).")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Srđan. Definitely makes sense. I love ReactiveKit, great work on it!